# Numbers in package name Android Studios

Tags: java, android, numbers, package, package-name

I'm trying to create an app ie "`1abcxyx`". When i create the project in Android studio's.

Ex.

```
App name:1abcxyz

Company domain:1abcxyz.com

Package name: com.1abcxyz.1abcxyz
```

*It creates the project location but the "next button" is grayed out. A disclaimer comes up and says I cant have # in the package name.*

I havent found a way around this.

Comment: Can you be more clear. Ex: by posting a screenshot or giving more details?

Comment: @hrskrs I just updated the question does that help? I'm away from my pc at the moment.

Comment: `A disclaimer comes up and says I cant have # in the package name.` It seems you already have an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) about naming packages in Java:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name

This means you can't use a digit as the first character of a package (or a class, interface or variable name, for that matter).

To clarify, you can name your app 1abcxyz, it's only the package name that cannot start with a digit (you could use `oneabcxyz` instead of `1abcxyz` for example). Having a package name different from your company's website should not influence communications between your app and your company's servers.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question:    So there's no way for me to go around this and name the app "1abcxyz"?

Comment: If memory serves, there's no issue in having your app name start with a digit, but as far as package names go, no, I don't think there's a way to have it *start* with a digit. I would use `oneabcxyz` instead of `1abcxyz`, or something like that just for package name. To the users of your app, package names should only be visible in the url of the Play Store page anyway.

Comment: Thanks: so i can name my app "1abcxyz" and change/edit the package name. The only problem might be the domain name is "1abcxyz.com" if i change it to "one" will it stop me from fecthing the data between the app and website?

Comment: Always glad to help ! And hopefully you won't let those blind downvotes get you down, there really was no reason for people to do this since IMHO your question was clear, well-worded and could be useful to others, but you know how internet gets sometimes... Still, there are enough bad questions to go around without needing to downvote this one.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for the support!